# Insert and retrieval from database in android (Stucked in infinite loop)

Tags: android, database

The problem is i inserted only two rows but on execution it enters into infinite loop and repeatedily showing the same data..Any kind of help would be appreciated
Here is my code.

This is my databse class (i.e DbAdapter)

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {
                String[]columns = new String[]{ KEY_MODEL,KEY_BRAND, KEY_PRICE};
                Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_LAPTOPS, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
                if (c != null) {
                    c.moveToLast();
                }
                return c;
}
```

This is my main class (i.e Laptops)

```
DbAdapter obj = new DbAdapter(this);
obj.open();
obj.insertRow("Dell1", "Dell", 345);
obj.insertRow("Hp1", "HP", 546);
obj.close();  



obj.open();
            Cursor c1 = obj.getAllRows();

            try{
                  if(c1 !=  null){
                  ListView empListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                  ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                  for(c1.moveToFirst();!c1.isAfterLast();c1.moveToNext())
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c1.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        //empListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data1));

            }}catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            obj.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c.moveToLast();
```

here is the issue

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

try this..

Comment: where and which is to use from both of the above?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Like This

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Assignment_VM_List);
```

---

```
AssignmentDatabaseConnector dao = new AssignmentDatabaseConnector(getActivity());
            List<AssignmentPojo> assignments = dao.getAllAssignmentList();
 AssignmentCustomAdapter assignmentCustomAdapter = new AssignmentCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                    assignments, this);
            listView.setAdapter(assignmentCustomAdapter);
```

---

### AssignmentDatabaseConnector :

```
public List<AssignmentPojo> getAllAssignmentList() {
        open();
        List<AssignmentPojo> assignmentList = new ArrayList<AssignmentPojo>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Assignment";

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { // ##Your Main Issue is Here ##
            do {
                AssignmentPojo assignment = new AssignmentPojo();
                assignment.setAssign_Id(cursor.getString(0));
                assignment.setAssign_Course(cursor.getString(1));
                

                // Adding contact to list
                assignmentList.add(assignment);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        // return contact list
        return assignmentList;
    }
```

This is just a sample code you can utilize this code according to your requirements